# Auto indent after inserting a semicolon or curly brace

Tags: emacs

```
GNU Emacs 24.3.1
```

Hello,

I am doing some coding in Java using emacs. Just to make my coding easier I want to auto indent each time I insert a semi-colon or curly brace {

```
;; Auto indent for java mode
(add-hook 'java-mode-hook '(lambda ()
      (local-set-key (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)))

(add-hook 'java-mode-hook '(lambda ()
      (local-set-key (kbd "{") 'newline-and-indent)))

(add-hook 'java-mode-hook '(lambda ()
      (local-set-key (kbd ";") 'newline-and-indent)))
```

The return works as expected. However, the curly brace and semi-colon just returns without entering the the `;` or `{`.

Is this possible?

many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: Last I checked (i.e. 30 seconds ago, with Emacs-24.3), java-mode already does that for you by default.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's possible. Here is one way of doing it (replace the second and third call to `add-hook` with this):

```lisp
(defun java-autoindent ()
  (when (and (eq major-mode 'java-mode) (looking-back "[{;]"))
    (newline-and-indent)))

(add-hook 'post-self-insert-hook 'java-autoindent)
```

The way this works is that every time you type a character in a `java-mode` buffer, Emacs will

- check if that character is `{` or `;`, and if that's the case
- run `newline-and-indent`.

Comment: I never knew about the post-self-insert-hook. I'm sure that'll come in useful in the future!